# The index of second, third,.. min with apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, min

I have a function where I am calculating the index of the minimum distance between a lat/long coordinate (in `SpatialPoints`) and another vector of coordinates (also in `SpatialPoints`). The function I use to find min dist is:

```
library(rgeos)
dfdist$mindist <-apply(gDistance(sp1, sp2, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
```

The function above gives me a column `mindist` in my pre-existing data frame `dfdist` which is an index of the row number of the point where the minimum distance occurs.

I'd like to also find the 2nd min distance, and the 3rd min dist, but am unsure of how to do this with the `apply()`. Is there a replacement for the `which.min` which will give me the index of the second min? Third min?

Comment: Maybe combine `which` with `rank`? As in: `which(rank(your_data)==2)`. Be aware of ties, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this user-defined function to do so:

```
f_which.min <- function(vec, idx) sort(vec, index.return = TRUE)$ix[idx]
```

So you can use:

```
apply(gDistance(sp1, sp2, byid=TRUE), 1, f_which.min, idx = 1)
```

Set the argument `idx` accordingly. That is, `idx=1` first min, `idx=2` second min and so on.

Comment: This rocks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use functions like the following:

```
which_nmin <- function(x, n = 1) 
{
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux <- ux[order(ux)][n]
  which(x == ux)
}

which_nmin(c(1, 1, 1, 1:5), 3)


which_nmax <- function(x, n = 1) 
{
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux <- ux[order(ux, decreasing = TRUE)][n]
  which(x == ux)
}

which_nmax(c(1, 1, 1, 1:5), 2)
```

Your `apply` call would be

```
apply(gDistance(sp1, sp2, byid=TRUE), 1, which_nmin, n = 2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this seems to minimize the latitude change of my vector of coordinates but does not minimize the function. I got crazy distances away from other coordinates. Is this just minimizing a single column?

Comment: Oops.  That's what I get for testing only on a monotonic vector.  These functions are corrected now.